# vb.net 2010 async report not working in GUI

Tags: vb.net, asynchronous

I know this is going to be virtually impossible to answer without me posting code, so I'll try to give some examples to aid this but...

I have a written dll which does some processing. I have it async tasks which report back status messages, such as the thing it's currently working on. There are multiple threads running each processing a different thing.

Now... when I use my DLL in a console app, the status.report("what I'm doing") works fine. I have a method in my console app with a Console.Writeline(text) which works great.

However... when I use the SAME dll in a gui form, and use the SAME methods from the console within the form to run the SAME processes with the SAME data, the SAME method that works perfectly writing the line to the console is NOT triggered and NO report is even processed by the gui.

Example.

console app:

```
Imports myDLL

Module Module1
    Sub Main
        SAE(paramaters).wait()
    End Sub

    Private Async Function SAE(parameters) as Task
        Dim progress_indicator As Progress(Of Integer) = New Progress(Of Integer)(AddressOf DisplayProgress)
        Dim progress_text As Progress(Of String) = New Progress(Of String)(AddressOf textProgress)
        Dim complete As Object = Nothing
        complete = Await Task.Run(Function() MyDLL.Process1(other parameters, progress_indicator, progress_text))
    End Function

    Private Sub DisplayProgress(ByVal percentage As Decimal)
        Console.WriteLine("percentage " + Format(percentage, "0.00"))
    End Sub

    Private Sub textProgress(ByVal text As String)
        Console.WriteLine("sub - reporting: " + text)
    End Sub
End Module 

Public Class myDLL
    Public Function SettleAll(other paramaters, progress_indicator As IProgress(Of Integer), status As IProgress(Of String)) As Boolean
        Dim aThread As Thread
        aThread = New Thread(Sub() _OtherProcess(other parameters, progress_indicator, status))
        aThread.Start()
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10)
        aThread.Join
    End Function

    Private Sub _OtherProcess(other parameters, progress_indicator, status))
        Loop
            'Do Some stuff...
            status.Report("Report back this it's working on this, that or the other")
            progress_indicator.Report(SomePercentageProgressVariable))      
        End Loop
    End Function 
End Class
```

Now... when I use this, I get messages in the console window as I expect. However... in the gui... when I copy the SAE method and put the Sub Main code into a button click like this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    SAE(paramaters).wait()
End Sub
```

... and I change the following methods:

```
Private Sub DisplayProgress(ByVal percentage As Decimal)
    Debug.Print("percentage " + Format(percentage, "0.00"))
End Sub
Private Sub textProgress(ByVal text As String)
    TextBox1.AppendText(text)
    Debug.Print("sub - reporting: " + text)
End Sub
```

NOTHING at all happens...

The DLL is doing the processing, but there's no reporting.

Answer (score 0):

Think I solved it.

If I change the button on_click method to an Async method llike this:

```
Private Async Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Await SAE(paramaters)
End Sub
```

It seems to work